# I wonder how the attribute 'items' works in this React code (The way of delivering this props)

Tags: reactjs

Parent Component!

```
<CarouselSlick 
    items={suffled || children}
    {…customFields}
    isSwipe={false}
    hideControlsMobile={false} 
/>
```

Child Component!

```
const CarouselSlick = (props) => {
  const {
    items = [],
    hideControlsMobile,
    isAutoPlay = false,
    isSwipe = true,
  } = props;
```

---

why is there an empty array?
As far as I know,

```
const { items } = props;
```

Above code is what I've known.
And why 'isSwipe' is getting 'true'? Its original value is false from Parent Component.
I have been watching only this code figure

```
const { items, hideControlsMobile, isAutoPlay, isSwipe } = props;
```

May I know how that is operating?

Comment: `isSwipe` must be false, that is default values concpt in javascript to variable initialization with default values if undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isSwipe must be false, that is default values concept in javascript to variable initialization with default values if undefined,
ECMAScript 2015 allows default parameter values as default values,

```
var i = {items:[1,2,3], isOk:false}
console.log(i)
{items: Array(3), isOk: false}

const {items} = i;
console.log(items)
(3) [1, 2, 3]

const {items = []} = i;
console.log(items)
(3) [1, 2, 3]

const {items = [], isOk = true} = i;
console.log(isOk)
false
```

in you case, name mismatch,

```
<CarouselSlick /> cant be child of <Carousel />
```

possible fix,

```
const Carousel = () => {

  return(
    <CarouselSlick 
      items={suffled || children}
      {…customFields}
      isSwipe={false}
      hideControlsMobile={false} 
    />
  )
}

const CarouselSlick = (props) => {
  const {
    items = [],
    hideControlsMobile,
    isAutoPlay = false,
    isSwipe = true,
  } = props;
```

Comment: Love you i really appreciate it from Korea

Answer (score 0):

Those are default values. Components in React are just like JS functions. If `CarouselSlick` component was called without `isSwipe` parameter it would be set to `false` inside the component. The same happens with items.

Example parent component :

```
<CarouselSlick
  {…customFields}
  hideControlsMobile={false} 
  isAutoPlay={true}
/>
```

Child component:

```
const CarouselSlick = (props) => {
  const {
  items = [],
  hideControlsMobile,
  isAutoPlay = false,
  isSwipe = true,
} = props;

// results
console.log(items)              // []
console.log(hideControlsMobile) // false
console.log(isAutoPlay)         // true
console.log(isSwipe)            // true
```

Comment: good answer with explanation of what exactly happening